# GM_xmlhttpRequest Data Attribute Not Working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, greasemonkey

I'm using a grease monkey script to simply send a GM_xmlhttpRequest to my locally hosted asp.net web service. The data attribute isn't working and I've looked at the github repository and haven't found anyone mentioning any issues.

There are a few StackOverFlow posts out there which say that adding a Content-Type resolves the problem, but for me is has not.

Here is my GM_xmlHttpRequest

```
(function() {
  console.log("Start Of Request");
  GM_xmlhttpRequest({
  method: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:8807/api/justSayHello",
  data: "input=hello",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  onload: function(response) {
    alert(response.responseText);
  },
   onerror:    function(reponse) {
       console.log("error: ", reponse);
   }
  });
    console.log("End Of Request");
})()
```

and here is my web service

```
  [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult justSayHello(string input)
        {
            if (input == null)
            {
                return Json("Did you just speak?", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            if (input.Equals("hello"))
            {
                return Json("hello back!", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
         return  Json("eh? Did you say something?", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

the result is "Did you just speak?" and what I would expect is "hello"

**A quick fix**

If i just concatanate the query string on the end then it works fine but I'd like to use the data attribute provided.

"http://localhost:8807/api/justSayHello?input=hello"

Comment: Try looking at the outgoing request in Fiddler or in the browser's devtools network panel. And try `'POST'` method.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the problem is resolved, the issue is that the data attribute only works for posts requests. Get requests read from the query string.

I changed this to a post request instead of get and it works perfectly